# relative homology is the reduced homology of the quotient

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I read in Hatcher page 124 that

> relative homology can be expressed as reduced absolute
>   homology in the case of good pairs $(X,A)$, but in fact there is a way of doing this for arbitrary pairs.

His argument goes as follows:
$\displaystyle \tilde{H_n}(X/A)= \tilde{H_n}(X ∪ CA) = H_n(X ∪ CA,CA) = H_n(X ∪ CA − \{p\},CA − \{p\}) = H_n(X,A)$

Where $p$ is the apex of $CA$ the cone on $A$.

So I understand that the relation  $\tilde{H_n}(X/A)=H_n(X,A)$ holds without any condition on the pair $(X,A)$ where $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is any non empty subset of $X$. Is my understanding correct ? thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is a misunderstanding.

Hatcher says that you can identify the relative homology group $H_n(X,A)$ of a *good pair* $(X,A)$ with the reduced homology
group $\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ of the *space* $X/A$. Good pairs are defined as those satisfying the hypothesis of Theorem 2.13. For example, CW-pairs are good.

This means that the homology groups of good pairs can be expressed as the (reduced) homology groups of suitable *single spaces*. This is possible for arbitrary pairs, though  in general **not** in the form $\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$, but in the form $\tilde{H}_n(X \cup CA)$ with the single space $X \cup CA$. There is an obvious quotient map $X \cup CA \to X/A$ which is a homotopy equivalence for good pairs (but not for general pairs).

Comment: Thank you @Paul Frost. I see your point.. what about the identification $X/A=(X\cup CA)/CA$ is this true for all pairs $(X,A)$ or only for good pairs ?

Comment: That is true for all pairs, but unfortunately the quotient map $p : X \cup CA \to (X \cup CA)/CA = X/A$ is in general not a homotopy equivalence. One can show that a quotient map $q : Y \to Y/B$ is a homotopy equivalence provided $B$ is contractible and the inclusion map $i : B \to Y$ is a cofibration.

Comment: To see that $X/A = (X \cup CA)/CA$, note that there is a natural embedding $j  : X \to X \cup CA$.Let $r : X \cup CA \to (X \cup CA)/CA$ denote the quotient map. Then $r \circ j$ maps $A$ to the point  obtained by collapsing $CA$, therefore it induces a continuous map $j' : X/A \to (X \cup CA)/CA$. Clearly $j'$ is a bijection and it is easy to show that it is an open map (i.e. a homeomorphism).

Comment: What is an example where $H_n(X,A)\not=\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ for all $n$?

Comment: @user13121312 This is a new question which cannot be answered in form of a comment. You should offcially ask for an example. Also see Hatcher Exercise 26 in Section 2.1.