# A question on relative homology and quotients

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have some trouble understanding the map on homology which is induced by a quotient map. If $(X,A)$ is a good pair, and $q:X\to X/A$ is the quotient map, is the induced map $q_*$ then given by the map $H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$ in the long exact chain, composed with the isomorphism $H_n(X,A)\cong H_n(X/A)$? If yes, why exactly? If no, then what is the best way to compute the induced map on homology of such a quotient map?

Thank you!

Comment: It should be the reduced homology $\tilde{H}_n(X/A)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [relative homology is the reduced homology of the quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825944/relative-homology-is-the-reduced-homology-of-the-quotient)

Comment: Partly. I still want to know where explicitly the map $q_*$ arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have an isomorphism $H_n(X,A) \approx H_n(X/A)$, but an isomorphism  $H_n(X,A) \approx \tilde H_n(X/A)$. See [relative homology is the reduced homology of the quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2825944). This shows that by excision $\tilde{H_n}(X ∪ CA) = H_n(X ∪ CA,CA) = H_n(X ∪ CA − \{p\},CA − \{p\}) = H_n(X,A)$. The answer invokes that the quotient map $X \cup CA \to X \cup CA / CA = X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence for *good pairs*.

Okay, for $n > 0$ we have $\tilde H_n(Y) = H_n(Y)$, but nevertheless it is conceptually essential that reduced homology gropus are involved. However, we can avoid the use of reduced homology via replacing $\tilde H_n(X/A)$ by the isomorphic group $H_n(X/A,*)$. The above considerations show that for good pairs $q : (X,A) \to (X/A,*)$ induces isomorphisms $q_* : H_n(X,A) \to H_n(X/A,*)$. But clearly the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(A)  @>{}>> H_n(X)  @>{}>> H_n(X,A) \\
@V{q_*}VV @V{q_*}VV @V{q_*}VV \\
H_n(*)  @>{}>> H_n(X/A) @>{}>> H_n(X/A,*) \end{CD}
commutes. For $n > 0$ the right bottom horizontal arrow is an isomorphism. For $n = 0$ it is an epimorphism with kernel isomorphic to $H_0(*) = \mathbb Z$. This should answer your question.